# Calcular, JavaScrips, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um script, que está calculando, só que ele me trás um inteiro, ou seja, se eu calcular os valores: 15,20 + 2,36 + 20,36 ele vai calcular somente os inteiros, vai me trazer o resultado sem a casa decimal.

```
<script>
    function calculatotal() {

        var valor = $('#Valor').val();
        var multa = $('#Multa').val();
        var juros = $('#Juros').val();
        var total = $('#Total').val();


        if (valor == "") valor = 0;
        if (multa == "") multa = 0;
        if (juros == "") juros = 0;
        if (total == "") total = 0;

        var adicao = parseFloat(valor) + parseFloat(multa) + parseFloat(juros);
         $('#Total').val(adicao);


    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Valor, #Multa,#Juros,#Total').blur(function () {
            calculatotal();
        });
        calculatotal();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {

        calculatotal(); // calcula imediatamente ao carregar a página
        $('#Valor, #Multa,#Juros,#Total')
            .blur(function () { calculatotal(); }) // calcula ao perder o foco
            .keyup(function () { calculatotal(); }); // calcula ao soltar a tecla


    });

</script>
```

Alguém pode me dar uma dica?

Comment: Vou dar uma dica: o JavaScript considera o padrão americano de moeda. A vírgula separa as casas de milhar e o ponto as decimais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o seu projeto esta trazendo o número decimal com virgula em vez de ponto, ele vai da erro na hora de calcular. Uma possível solução seria você substituir a virgula por ponto e caso ele esteja vindo como string basta converter para float, e por fim para mostrar duas casas decimais igual moeda você pode usar o toFixed, caso queira mostrar o total para o usuário com virgula em vez de ponto já que o nosso padrão é virgula, substitui na variável total. Segue abaixo um exemplo:

```
var valor = '10.10';
var multa = '5,50';
var juros = '5,50';

valor = parseFloat(valor.replace(",", "."));
multa = parseFloat(multa.replace(",", "."));
juros = parseFloat(juros.replace(",", "."));

var total = valor+multa+juros;
total = total.toFixed(2);
total = total.replace(".", ",");
alert(total);
```